# endfloat and \newcommand incompatibility

Tags: macros, endfloat

I have a lot of figures and tables defined using `\newcommand{\NAMEOFTABLE}{\begin{table}...\end{table}}` and I would like to use them with `endfloat` package.  Here is a MWE that demonstrates the problem:

```
\newcommand{\tableA}{\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c}
text \\
text \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{A test delayed table}%
\end{table}%
}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tablesonly,nomarkers]{endfloat}

\begin{document}

\section{test}
\tableA

\end{document}
```

which yields the output

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\\ ->\let \reserved@e
\relax \let \reserved@f \relax \@ifstar {\let \reserv...
l.17 \tableA
```

I have found that switching from a `\newcommand` to an environment does work:

```
\newenvironment{tableA}{\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c}
text \\
text \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{A test delayed table}%
\end{table}%
}{}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tablesonly,nomarkers]{endfloat}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{tableA}{table}

\begin{document}

\section{test}
\begin{tableA}
\end{tableA}

\end{document}
```

but I don't want to have to

1. list all the environments with `\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor`
2. rename all the `\newcommand` as environments

How can I make this work?

Comment: I think this might be an auto-generated comment, but yes, the MWE are compilable

Comment: While it might be 'convenient' at first glance to use a bypass for `\begin....\end` it will turn out as very tedious later on. The error is most probably from the definition of `\\` in `latex.ltx`

Comment: The primary reason I was doing that before was because I needed to manually put the figure either in the text or at the end depending on the desired output format, and now that I have the endfloat package, that is less of a concern.  Why will it not parse instances of \tableA properly?